# how to sort arrays that pointed by pointers array?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

I need to sort arrays that pointed by pointers array
with this function (i need only with pointers, without these [ ])

```
void getSort(int** p2a, int arrSizes[]) //p2a is a array of pointers to diffrent arrays
```

I tried bubble sort:

```
if (i < 5)
{
    for (j = 1; j < arrSizes[i]; j++) // I started with 1 bcz i dont want to sort the first value
    {
        for (k = j + 1; k < arrSizes[i]; k++)
        {
            if (*(*(p2a + i) + j) > *(*(p2a + i) + k))
            {
                temp = *(*(p2a + i) + j);
                *(*(p2a + i) + j) = *(*(p2a + i) + k);
                *(*(p2a + i) + k) = temp;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

but it not sorting well...
exampels:

- Before: 3 9 3 7
- After: 3 3 9 7
- Before: 3 6 1 7
- After: 3 1 6 7
- Before: 4 9 7 1 7
- After: 4 9 7 1 7

Comment: can you also show the part where you storing your list in p2a variable.

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));

 int i = 0, j = 0; 
 int arrSizes[NUM] = { 4, 3, 1, 2, 5 };
 int** p2a = (int*)malloc(NUM * sizeof(int*));

 for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
 {
  *(p2a + i) = (int*)malloc(arrSizes[i] * sizeof(int));
  *(*(p2a + i) + 0) = arrSizes[i] - 1;
 }
 
 for (i = 0; i <= NUM; i++)
 {
  for (j = 1; j < arrSizes[i]; j++)
  {
   *(*(p2a + i) + j) = rand() % 10;
  }
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the if with for solved the problem

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j < arrSizes[i]; j++)
    {
        for (k = j + 1; k < arrSizes[i]; k++)
        {
            if (*(*(p2a + i) + j) > *(*(p2a + i) + k))
            {
                temp = *(*(p2a + i) + j);
                *(*(p2a + i) + j) = *(*(p2a + i) + k);
                *(*(p2a + i) + k) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```